# Parcelable CREATOR understanding

Tags: android, parcelable

I can't understand the way of work with Parcelable. Especially it is hard to understand why CREATOR property is needed. Why we need to implement such complex constraction instead of implement readFromParcel(Parcel in) for example?

Answer (score 0):

You need a CREATOR to generate instance of your Parcelable class from a Parcel. 
What this means is you are creating object of your parceled class with all class member variables initialized from Parcel. You cannot access class variables directly from parcel.